# Reset All Items after Click on any new Item - RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Actually I want to acheive the fucntionality in which **whenever i click on new Item the old one should be reset**, I have changed the color and background by setting click listener on viewholder in Adapter but dont know to reset the previuos one.

[image: Here at the second layout i want to acheive that functionality]

here is the source code of Adapter

`

```
public class DateAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DateAdapter.VH> {
    private List<DateModel> driverListModelList;
    private ClickListener clickListener;

    public DateAdapter(List<DateModel> driverListModelList, ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.driverListModelList = driverListModelList;
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DateAdapter.VH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.date_item, parent, false);
        return new DateAdapter.VH(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DateAdapter.VH holder, int position) {

        holder.setData(driverListModelList.get(position).getDay(), driverListModelList.get(position).getMonth(),
                driverListModelList.get(position).getDate());


        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            holder.itemView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(holder.itemView.getContext(), R.drawable.day_bar_item2));
            holder.day.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            holder.month.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            holder.date.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return driverListModelList.size();
    }

    class VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private TextView day;
        private TextView month;
        private TextView date;

        @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
        public VH(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            day = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dayTxt);
            month = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtMonth);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);

//            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            
        }

        private void setData(final String day, final String month, final String date) {
            this.day.setText(day);
            this.month.setText(month);
            this.date.setText(date);
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            clickListener.onItemClicked(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

`

i tried by recyclerView.invalidate(); and notifiyDataSetChanged();

Comment: on button click just call api and clear old list and insert new data came from api.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SparseBooleanArray or ArrayList of integers with ids/position of selected elements. Then in onBindViewHolder, check the ids/position is and change background color and in onClick add ids/position in SparseBooleanArray or ArrayList.